# Is there a way to remove columns in the Version Control window of CLion?

Tags: ide, clion, jetbrains-ide

The CLion Version Control Window (cmd+9 on Mac) is a disaster of overlapping columns and way-too-many-windows.  I do, however, prefer their diff presentation to that of GitLab.

Is there a way to remove or collapse columns from at least the Log / branch window? For example, if I wanted to remove author, tag, and date, and just see the branches and their commit messages?

Comment: [2019.2 EAP](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2019/05/intellij-idea-starts-the-2019-2-early-access-program/): Ability to customize VCS Log columns: https://d3nmt5vlzunoa1.cloudfront.net/idea/files/2019/05/VCSLogColumn.png VCS is a platform-wide functionality, so will be available in CLion as well.

Comment: @LazyOne can you make this an answer?

Answer (score 1):

In next major version (2019.2, will be released soon) you can customize VCS Log columns.

From https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2019/05/intellij-idea-starts-the-2019-2-early-access-program/

> **Ability to customize VCS Log columns**
>
> You will be able to choose the columns that will be displayed in the VCS Log tab. Simply click on the eye icon, select the ‘Show Columns’ item from the context menu, and then select the columns you want to see: Author, Date, or commit hash.

[image]